Syntax of both try/catch and setting OnSuccess/OnFailure listeners on signInWithEmailAndPassword?
I am writing some Kotlin classes to log in to an app using Firebase email/pass login. Currently, the function is:
fun loginWithFirebase(email : String, password : String)
    {
        setInProgress(true)
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            UiUtil.showToast(this, "Logged in successfully")
            setInProgress(false)
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener{
            UiUtil.showToast(applicationContext, it.localizedMessage?: "Login failed, something went wrong")
            setInProgress(false)
        }
    }

I want to add a try/catch to catch exceptions from signInWithEmailAndPassword, such as in this question, but this syntax is thorny and I'm having trouble figuring out where to place the try/catch block so it doesn't break the success and failure listeners.
I know that telling the user that they got only the username wrong or only the password wrong is a bad idea, and I'm not trying to disable Firebase anti-user enumeration measures. I'd like to keep those on.
Thank you!


I want to add a try/catch to catch exceptions from signInWithEmailAndPassword, such as in this question

There is no need to add a try/catch when using listeners. If the operation of signing in with email and password fails, then onFailure(Exception e) method fires. This method has an argument of type Exception. You can then call getMessage() to see the actual error message.
Besides that, the code in the linked question is JavaScript, which has a different syntax. But in Kotlin code, there is no need for that, unless you're using Kotlin Coroutines and you await the result. Please check an answer provided a few days ago:

How do you listen for errors when uploading synchronously to Firebase storage?

